# Conflict between memoir class and float package?

Tags: floats, memoir

I'm trying to put a table float in a book manuscript that uses the `memoir` class. This used to work fine until a few days ago, when I ran an update using the TexLive utility. (I think the `memoir` class got updated recently.) I now get the following baffling error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `\'.
```

even though I'm loading the `float` package without any options.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{This is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The example code compiles fine if I replace the `memoir` class with either `article` or `book`.

Comment: hm, the way float redefines `\@xfloat` doesn't go well with the cmd-hook used by memoir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic `cmd/xxx/after` hooks are rather fragile. If they work depends a lot on the actually definition of the command `\xxx`. As float redefines `\@xfloat` it breaks as soon as the hook is declared (even if it is empty).

It would probably be safer if memoir would put its code into `\@floatboxreset` instead of patching `\@xfloat`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\DisableGenericHook{cmd/@xfloat/after} %disable the \@xfloat hook alltogether

\AddToHook{cmd/@floatboxreset/after}{% reinstate the memoir code
 \def\baselinestretch{\m@m@float@spacing}%
    \normalsize%
    \@nameuse{\@captype adjustment}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{This is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand much of this, but since it solved the problem I'm marking this as the correct answer.